# creating a class using typescript with specific fields

Tags: typescript, class

I would like to create a fairly flexible class called Model, like:

```
export class Model {
    _required_fields: Array<string> = [];
    _optional_fields?: Array<string> = [];

    constructor(params: Dictionary<string> = {}) {
        // make sure all required fields are in the params obj
    }

    set(params: Dictionary<string>){
        // make sure only required or optional fields are present

        this.all_fields.forEach(key => {
            this[key] = params[key];
        });
    }

    get all_fields(): Array<string> {
        return [...this._required_fields,...this._optional_fields];
    }

    get required_fields() {
        return this._required_fields;
    }
}
```

children of this will define the required and optional fields and I've kept this shorter because I had some error checking in the `set` method.  For example:

```
export class User extends Model {
    static REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username'];
    static OPTIONAL_FIELDS = ['email'];

    get required_fields() {
        return (this._required_fields?.length==0) ? User.REQUIRED_FIELDS : [];
    }

    static get ALL_FIELDS() {
        return [...User.REQUIRED_FIELDS, ...User.OPTIONAL_FIELDS];
    }

    constructor(params: Dictionary<string> = {}) {
      super(params);
    }
}
```

I have a version of `User` with the fields:

```
username: string;
email: string;
```

but I'd like to be able to define the fields so the `set` function can take a `Dictionary` and fill in the fields as shown.

I'm getting the typescript error `No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Model'.` at the line:

```
this[key] = params[key];
```

and I realize this because I would need to define a field like: `[key: string]: string;` inside of `Model`.

There seems to be two possibilities with this:

**Method 1**: Inside of `User`, define each of the fields and inside of `set` (of `User`) explicitly do

```
user.username = params.username;
user.email = params.email;
```

I have to repeat this for all children of Model, however, and I have some error checking for this that I'd like to automate a bit.

**Method 2**: Alternatively, I could keep Model having the generic field

```
[key: string]: string;
```

and then `set` will work as is, but won't have the ability to do `user.username`, but could do `user['username']`.

**summary**

I have done method 1 so far and there is a ton of repeated code, because I need to do all of the fields explicitly for each of the children of `Model`. (I realistically I have much more that 2 fields).  This isn't satisfying it seems like I could write things much more compactly in the `Model` class instead of each child.

Method 2 seems like it by bypasses much of the strong typing of typescript, so although the code is more compact, it doesn't seem great.

**Question**

Is there any way I could structure this to blend the strong typing of typescript with the flexibility of Method 1

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WPjLKN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Is [this code](https://tsplay.dev/w8AnVN) something like what you're looking for?  Class declarations can't have dynamic property keys, but you can get something like that behavior with a class factory function and judicious uses of type assertions.  If there's something missing or broken in my suggested solution, please ensure your code example demonstrates the use cases that it fails to satisfy.

Comment: @jcalz, I think this is precisely what I'm looking for.  The `Record` type in typescript allows that blend I was looking for.  Can you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want `Model` to be keep track of the actual [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) values in the  `requiredFields` and `optionalFields` elements, which implies that `Model` should maybe be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in these types.  So maybe something like `Model<R, O>` where `R` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all the required keys and `O` is the union of all the optional keys.

But you also want a `Model<R, O>` to actually *have* keys of type `R` and `O`.  And that's where we get into trouble with regular old `class` statements.   Classes and interfaces require that their keys be *statically known* to the compiler.  They cannot be dynamic and filled in later:

```
class Foo<T extends object > implements T {} // error!
// -----------------------------------> ~
// A class can only implement an object type or intersection 
// of object types with statically known members.
```

So we'll need to work around this.

---

It's easy enough to *describe* such a class constructor type.  It should look *something* like this

```
type ModelConstructor = new <R extends string, O extends string>(
    params: ModelObject<R, O>
) => ModelObject<R, O> & {
    set(params: Partial<ModelObject<R, O>>): void,
    all_fields: Array<R | O>;
    required_fields: R[];
}

type ModelObject<R extends string, O extends string> =
    Record<R, string> & Partial<Record<O, string>>;
```

So a `ModelConstructor` has a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) which takes a `params` of type `ModelObject<R, O>`.  The `ModelObject<R, O>` is an object type with required keys `R` and optional keys `O` and whose values are all `string`.  The constructed instance is also a `ModelObject<R, O>` which is [intersected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with a set of appropriately typed properties and methods that you have in your `Model` class.

Before moving on with this, though, it might be useful to think about how you want to subclass `Model`.  Since you would like every single instance of, say, `User`, to have the same required and optional fields, it might make sense to make `Model` a *class factory function* instead of a `class` constructor itself.  Otherwise you need to redundantly specify `R` and `O`:

```
class AnnoyingUser extends Model<"username", "email"> {
    _required_fields = ["username"] // redundant
    _optional_fields = ["email"] // redundant
}
```

It might be a lot nicer to just write

```
class User extends Model(["username"], ["email"]) { }
```

where `Model(["username"], ["email"])` produces a class constructor with those fields already in place.  It's up to you whether or not you want to do it this way.  I'm going to assume that a factory function is acceptable and keep going with it.

---

So here's the factory function:

```
export const Model = <R extends string, O extends string>(
    requiredFields: R[], optionalFields: O[]
) => {

    type ModelObject =
        Record<R, string> & Partial<Record<O, string>> extends
        infer T ? { [K in keyof T]: T[K] } : never;

    class _Model {
        _required_fields: Array<R> = requiredFields;
        _optional_fields?: Array<O> = optionalFields;

        constructor(params: ModelObject) {
            this.set(params);
        }

        set(params: Partial<ModelObject>) {
            this.all_fields.forEach(key => {
                (this as any)[key] = (params as any)[key];
            });
        }

        get all_fields(): Array<R | O> {
            return [...this._required_fields,
            ...this._optional_fields ?? []];
        }

        get required_fields() {
            return this._required_fields;
        }
    }

    return _Model as any as new (params: ModelObject) =>
        ModelObject & {
            set(params: Partial<ModelObject>): void,
            all_fields: Array<R | O>;
            required_fields: R[];
        } extends infer T ? { [K in keyof T]: T[K] } : never;
}
```

Note that the class constructor returned from `Model` [closes over](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) the `requiredFields` and `optionalFields` variables passed into it.

The typings are similar to before, except that `R` and `O` are now generic type parameters on the factory function and not the resulting class.  The scope is a little different, so (for example) `ModelObject` doesn't need to be generic in `R` and `O` since `R` and `O` are known in that scope.  Also there are some `extends infer T ? {[K in keyof T]: T[K]}: never` types thrown in there, which are there just to ask the compiler to expand out things like `Record<"username", string> & Partial<Record<"email", string>>` into a nicer looking `{username: string; email?: string}` type.

Also note that since the compiler cannot represent a `class` as having dynamic properties, I need to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that it can treat the returned constructor as the right type.

Once you use a factory function you could decide to refactor further; maybe you want the required/optional fields to only be `static` properties of the returned class constructor, since they should be the same for every instance of the class.  I'm not going to bother, though.  Just a thought.

---

Let's test it out. First let's see what comes out when we call `Model`:

```
const UserModel = Model(["username"], ["email"]);
/* const UserModel: new (params: {
    username: string;
    email?: string | undefined;
}) => {
    username: string;
    email?: string | undefined;
    set: (params: Partial<{
        username: string;
        email?: string | undefined;
    }>) => void;
    all_fields: ("username" | "email")[];
    required_fields: "username"[];
} */
```

Seems reasonable, and what you want, I think.  Now we can define `User`:

```
export class User extends Model(["username"], ["email"]) {
    // static REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username'];
    // static OPTIONAL_FIELDS = ['email'];
}
```

Those `static` properties I commented out were from your example, but they are not necessary for my solution. If you want them, feel free to add them, but I don't know what purpose they serve.

Let's test it out:

```
const u = new User({ username: "alice" });
console.log(u.required_fields) // ["username"]
console.log(u.all_fields) // ["username", "email"]
u.set({ email: "foo@example.com" })
console.log(u.email) // foo@example.com
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&ts=4.4.3#code/LAKA9GAEDGA2CGBnRkBiB7dAeAKgPkgEsBbAB1gFNiKA7AFxR0gG8BfSSUCSAQRgWQx4NSOhqwAnkTKVq9SMNEAjAFYVodSHQmkKogE5F6FfYnV1CY0QDNlajVp0UUAd0J0AFpER14F6PCwkpAA1jToLiLUxEomiAB0oKA08NSIpPDQegBy6HQA4voUfiygHBx0+lLMZeV12rqQALLoACYUsADCYj76AK4a6IYAvJA0FC6QWABKkBQAHnS0rSi9hDQA5gA0kADyc4vLq5XrG3gAFLV115AZ+qmIAFzNbR27quYzO7t4V9cAlJBhgQWu1YO97HQvnsCAAyUogG43Mx0c53B7PAAK8H0FkCWFBbw+GmhPzw-2eADd0IRWls-kiFEEAPrWQgdFbPHj6e4SGaQAA+MIA3AykUUAI59QhFVqs9mwTmQaYAbQAuqLEUjWEktTcGnpCeDiVDZgsljQVt4TptvgcLVa1psCMMxTdpuohq1oU6zpB4djcYR8R7oF6sLsdr68HhNW7IJScS8wc8jd0aL0BnQhkCxn0ggBCON665wJAoHg0cISU4AVTMhnNR2THSwACI+g2UtQ2zs21R4IRYG2CDUS4zmZLpbL5RyUKMVR2u6kKG21fG6sz0KQLGJArPFfPIIuB0O1-GdSX2AE6NAvOcKIDmJBL5fdQtSENNGGM5ojbn+SbS1jn0U47SAx0bTOS4SynGUKFaVAFSVVU1R2bddxSWAkLnZ5dnVUBAWBBE-gNFtjUhIF41DcNpijKC4UgQM8VgGZPX0b1I2tUDnQICDEHjdZrBMSAmAAfhYY8AGkjFCCgJHQWwcDVZ4cBVKS1RfSBnnGSkTGLOoy0EZl-zHCc4JnNlcN4Hl4D5aYXUgCyEJww9NQnDDLCwg8VjErlbL5H5c08vdsOQxADKRH9M0GfQ0RxDFyIhcwnw3cpPEIBIUXi+5iEQf53O1XVGWy9E8qxHEWIJV4KPMckEUZeoPEy+JAlgHyEmsIYAFFMg8c4QnkoFRzSm5zgylAkAUGgJH+FVBokTTRhyh4FEmma5oWjVRpfAqL2KpENgoTQ2o684KRs3l+SFIKzMajgijoPp9BEFV4neib4knCgpXguUrMPelxyRd74k+rcdy8-cAatMSJPVbbgY4N8kcgI7NGc-7wvOhr7qc47npEcHMY6wqbkvOoUbqR7CcgEyarW6apCm8ZJhW8qkpNIjflRo1koceE7vu0qEo55jg1YvmTXJKkaTpHbTphp5Lrs66RR2kmleeVCyeudh+KMYTDHEyT1NkhbFNElTRPUzT2B0ig9P0TUUeizR6xMf9RiNc5F07Exu1XNDj37YhB2HNU9vAAAqGAendhsjQdtmyuVoXIH9l6V2eX1ddPWA-O405BQzy0KDZcZWhd7ncY4TPA5zqC87DodC99Eu+jLiuEN1lFnnZ5XxfxdO6nr7Oi82XW6nztuoI7rv1h7v5WHq4jqVpXXFfC-ulwDlc2xL0Pw7bObEepn7pwQjrnl3rOe3VF3IGjsBdVAD8v34ctIA9xtDmA8jfa30DmuHYJ4W4R1SiWbgPg-CEGgMqbqABFWsABJaY3UAAizJUAoO6gAGQwQAZVzCqAA5GPagpCNScCgVAGB-g9iYhwCg3Y2QeB4OwbgghxCFykPzlQl2uo3YZ1zKzb+DZzjPgoRQG+gQ4Grl2pqaK6BKDxFgOgDY5w+jxE1uFQE3A-bLh7OuEAyjVHqM0dorec59FQEMXvHsfZ87nhANo7Kz5843y6ugAAAgsVI5AKDxDDMQA+rB-igDMUEixWj4j51sZAbxfj5gBNUSEoAA)

Comment: This looks like the balance I was looking for.  

The static fields were to be used other places in the code to access the fields without making an object.  That is why I have them in there, but perhaps I may not need them.