# Typescript Mixin with Class Factory

Tags: typescript, mixins

I have a Class factory that has been derived from [creating a class using typescript with specific fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69590729/creating-a-class-using-typescript-with-specific-fields), but I'd like to do more with this.

I trimmed things down to the following:

```
interface Dictionary {
    [k: string]: string | number;
}

const Model = <F extends string>(fields: F[]) => {
    type ModelObject<F extends string> = Partial<Record<F, string>>

    class _Model {
        _fields: F[] = fields;

        constructor(params: Dictionary) {
            Object.keys(params).forEach(key => {
                (this as unknown as Dictionary)[key] = params[key];
            });
        }

        set(params: Dictionary) {
            Object.keys(params).forEach(key => {
                (this as unknown as Dictionary)[key] = params[key];
            });
        }
    }
    return _Model as unknown as new (params?: Dictionary) =>
        ModelObject<F> & {set(params: Dictionary): void};
};
```

and this works as expected if I do:

```
class User extends Model(['username', 'email']) {}
const fred = new User({ username: 'fred', email: 'fred@mydomain.com' });
fred.username; // 'fred'
```

I'd like to apply additional functionality using a mixin.  Looking at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html, there are multiple ways, but I'm running into the problem in any of the ways.  I think this is because this is a factory rather than a simple class as in the documentation.

For example, consider:

```
function AdminMixin<TBase extends typeof Model>(Base: TBase) {
    return class Admin extends Model(['can_delete']) {

        delete() {
            // delete privileges
        }
    };
}
```

I would like to do:

```
const AdminUser = AdminMixin(User);
const harriet = new AdminUser({ username: 'harriet' });
harriet.delete();
```

However, on the `AdminMixin` line, I'm getting the following error:

```
Argument of type 'typeof User' is not assignable to parameter of type '<F extends string>(fields: F[]) => new (params?: Dictionary | undefined) => Partial<Record<F, string>> & { set(params: Dictionary): void; }'.
  Type 'typeof User' provides no match for the signature '<F extends string>(fields: F[]): new (params?: Dictionary | undefined) => Partial<Record<F, string>> & { set(params: Dictionary): void; }'.ts(2345)
```

It appears that they are the same type, but clearly typescript is not picking this up.  I'm running under version 4.4.3.

Comment: Here was another go at it:  Changing the `AdminMixin` to

Comment: Ignore that above, wouldn't let me edit it....

Here was another go at it:  Changing the top of `AdminMixin` to

`function AdminMixin(M: typeof Model) {
 return class Admin extends M(['can_delete']) {
`

Now only results in a runtime error of 

`
TypeError: Class constructor User cannot be invoked without 'new'
`
and this seems to be a possible problem with babel and using older target ecmascripts.  I have specified es2020.